# Child process read from pipe failed and seemed to be out of order

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I have the following code with output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>

#define PIPE_STDIN  0
#define PIPE_STDOUT 1

#define msg "hello world"

int main()
{
   int fd_pipe[2];

   int ret = fork();
   if (ret < 0)
   {
       printf("Failed to fork\n");
       return -1;
   }
   else if (ret == 0)
   {
       printf("Parent with PID %d\n", getpid());    fflush(stdout);
       //sleep(3);
       ret = write(fd_pipe[PIPE_STDOUT], msg, sizeof(msg));   fflush(stdout);
       printf("Parent wrote string %d\n", ret);     fflush(stdout);
       wait( NULL );
       printf("Parent done wait\n");    fflush(stdout);
   }
   else
   {
       char buf[80];
       printf("Child with PID %d whose parent PID %d\n", getpid(), ret);    fflush(stdout);
       ret = read(fd_pipe[PIPE_STDIN], buf, sizeof(msg));
       printf("Child read %s %d\n", buf, ret);  fflush(stdout);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Child with PID 1130 whose parent PID 1131
Child read   -1
Parent with PID 1131
hello world Parent wrote string 12
Parent done wait
```

From the output, why would child failed to read from pipe (returned -1) and then later on message "hello world" was printed ? Please explain the execution order that gives the above log.

Comment: You don't show where you call `pipe()` — you're using randomish file descriptors.

Comment: The `fflush(stdout)` after the `write()` call is mostly a no-op.

Comment: Common sense dictates the result of `fork()` to be the child process' pid number, as the parent process pid can be always get with the `getppid()` system call, but there's no means to get the pid of a child in UNIX but to get it directly from `fork()` syscall.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `write()` is under `fflush()` implementation.  It knows nothing about buffers  (it is not part of `stdio`), so there can be data in the buffer, if you **only** do a `write(2)` syscall.  Nothing to say if he had used `fwrite(3)` instead.

Comment: @LuisColorado — yes, but the call before the `write()` was also `fflush(stdout)` so the one afterwards has nothing to do, as I said.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, oh... then all is alright... :)

Comment: at your taste.... I'll do with mine. Change the order of `fflush(stdout)` **before** `write()` in yours and I'll delete all my comments.  The idempotent one is the one done **before** the `write()` call, and not the one after it.

Comment: I can't agree that the one before the write is the idempotent one, @LuisColorado.  I'd like to remove all the comments, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should call `pipe` before `fork` to init file descriptor.
2. `fork() == 0` means child process.

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>

#define PIPE_STDIN  0
#define PIPE_STDOUT 1

#define msg "hello world"

int main()
{
   int fd_pipe[2];
   int ret;

   if (pipe(fd_pipe) == -1) {
       perror("pipe");
       return -1;
   }
   ret = fork();
   if (ret < 0)
   {
       printf("Failed to fork\n");
       return -1;
   }
   else if (ret != 0)
   {
       printf("Parent with PID %d\n", getpid());    fflush(stdout);
       //sleep(3);
       ret = write(fd_pipe[PIPE_STDOUT], msg, sizeof(msg));   fflush(stdout);
       printf("Parent wrote string %d\n", ret);     fflush(stdout);
       wait( NULL );
       printf("Parent done wait\n");    fflush(stdout);
   }
   else
   {
       char buf[80];
       printf("Child with PID %d whose parent PID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());    fflush(stdout);
       ret = read(fd_pipe[PIPE_STDIN], buf, sizeof(msg));
       printf("Child read %s %d\n", buf, ret);  fflush(stdout);
   }
}
```